# about the most expensive coffee

Tags: kopiluwak

is there anyone who has an idea about Kopi luwak like ? how it tests and what makes it different from others.do we use the same coffee making procedure for it tooo?

Comment: First of all it is not the most expensive coffee in the world and secondly these questions have been asked before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kopi Luwak coffee beans](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/kopi-luwak-coffee-beans)

Comment: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/kopi-luwak-coffee-beans
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/kopi-luwak-real-or-not
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/139/is-kopi-luwak-safe-to-drink
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/what-does-kopi-luwak-taste-like
Definitely a duplicate